# Reboot after update

Tags: updates, update-manager

One of the most favorite arguments of linux-lovers in disputes with windows-lovers is linux haven't to reboot after upgrade. So, why every time I upgraded my Ubuntu with update manager it asks me to reboot?
UPD:
I'm telling about common software updates. And not distributive not kernel upgrades at that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It generally only asks for a reboot when a new kernel is installed, which happens somewhat regularly. That can be avoided by using [the Canonical Livepatch service](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch).

The current instructions listed on that website for enabling that are:

1. Generate your credentials via the [Canonical Livepatch portal](https://auth.livepatch.canonical.com/)
2. Install the canonical-livepatch daemon:

   ```
   sudo snap install canonical-livepatch
   ```
3. Enable it:

   ```
   sudo canonical-livepatch enable [TOKEN]
   ```

Comment: Can I use it for Elementary OS?

Comment: Sorry, that distribution is not really supported here, and I'm not sure whether it works there.